# Как объявить новый Cropper JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Использую [Cropper.js](https://github.com/fengyuanchen/cropperjs/blob/master/README.md)

Хочу изменить размер картинки после загрузки ее на сервер.

После первой загрузки файла, заменяю src на адрес картинки и подключаю Cropper

```
    $('.main-demo-image').attr("src","/storage/profile_images/"+response.data.file_name);

    var $image=$(".main-demo-image"),
    options={
      viewMode:1,aspectRatio:4/4, preview:".img-preview",crop:function(e){
      }
    };
    $image.cropper(options);
```

Все работает, но когда я загружаю новую фотографию(Вторую, без обновления страницы) и пробегаюсь по коду выше(Меняю src и применяю cropper), фотография не меняется.

Я так понимаю нужно как-то применить New для cropper, но не знаю как

Вопрос, как мне удалить старую картинку(cropper) и добавить новую
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для замены изображения вначале нужно выполнить `crop_cropper.destroy();` после чего инициализировать `Cropper` с новым изображением.

```js
$(function() {
  var crop_image;
  var crop_cropper;
  var crop_cropper_options = {
    /* свои опции для Cropper */
  };

  crop_image = document.getElementById('image1');
  crop_cropper = new Cropper(crop_image, crop_cropper_options);

  $("#test1").on("click", function() {
    crop_cropper.destroy();
    crop_image = document.getElementById('image1');
    crop_cropper = new Cropper(crop_image, crop_cropper_options);
  });
  $("#test2").on("click", function() {
    crop_cropper.destroy();
    crop_image = document.getElementById('image2');
    crop_cropper = new Cropper(crop_image, crop_cropper_options);
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.4.1/cropper.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/cropperjs/1.4.1/cropper.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <img id="image1" src="1.jpg">
  <img id="image2" src="2.jpg">
</div>
<button type="button" id="test1">test img1</button>
<button type="button" id="test2">test img2</button>
```